# JavaScript Method within Method

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, nested

I would need to declare Methods within Methods and call them outside as a Object, Method connotation... 
To make it more clear:

I need to call:

```
Object.Method().nestedMethod();
```

how can I do it so? This failed so far:

```
function Object(){ 
     this.Method = function(){

          this.Method.nestedMethod = function(){

          };

     };

}
```

As I work on a DSL it is necessary to call a Method within a Method. In this case the last Method is some kind of recursion Method of the previous one, like this:

```
Object.execute(param).recursion();
```

How would I have to declare the nested Method to access this so?

Comment: Why exactly ? What's the real purpose ? Do you want, in fact, chaining ?

Comment: Yes, I writing some kind of DSL, and need to chain the Methods... And, I'm also giving parameters, so when calling Object.Method(param).nestedMethod(); - nestedMethod needs to know "param"...

Answer (score 1):

You can return an object that contains `nestedMethod`:

```
Object.Method = function () {
    return {
        nestedMethod: function () {}
    };
}
```

Comment: A `new Object` would be needed to call that (with a different name than `"Object"`, hopefully)

Comment: Don't works really for me... Can you go more in detail?

Comment: @DamianT.Dziwis What does it return for you when you call `Object.Method().nestedMethod();`?

Comment: It returns nothing, I need to write a recursion function... Maybe this makes it more clear:  Procedure.execute(param).loop(cycles);  - so loop will call execute(param) in cycle times... Its necessary to do it nested...